# Why is the scanf() function printing to my standard output stream? How do I suppress this behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, clion

I am compiling this code using the MinGW gcc compiler using CLion 1.0.5. I am observing weird behavior with this function, and I'm not sure if it's my compiler or IDE causing this problem. Basically, my IDE console is repeating back to me whatever I typed into the standard input stream. Here are some example inputs and outputs.

```
123NotAnInteger
123NotAnInteger
```

---

```
123
123
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int age;
    scanf("%d", &age);
}
```

Comment: I do not think this would be possible without a `printf` statement just after the `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf(3)` never prints any output.

Comment: This is not related to C language, per se. It appears to be a bug in your IDE.

Comment: You probably have something misconfigured or running perhaps an executable that did that. scanf does not to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your IDE. I ran the above code using gcc 4.7, and there was no output.

Comment: I tried using the same compiler in a different environment, and you're right.